# Use ChromeView in Android App

Tags: android, webview, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use ChromeView on my Android app in order to run some preload html. I follow this tutorial https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview

I can import it correctly to my project, but i can't see the ChromeView component on the Pallete, as it is mentioned there, so my app crashes because "Class Not Found" exception is raised.

Thanks in advise

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented this and It worked.  Hopefully it helps someone.
Here's how I did it:

Instead of looking for `ChromeView` on the Pallete, I would recommend that you just type it in the XML.  Much quicker.

Here's how:
[image]

BUT, if you prefer to do it in the design mode, look for `Custom View` on the Pallete.

[image]

And when you click on it, it will show all the custom views available from the linked libraries, etc. Pick `ChromeView` from the list.

[image]

If `ChromeView` is not on that list and if you manually type it in XML and give you error, the chromeview package isn't linked correctly.